# Are PhoneGap and Apache Cordova real servers?

Tags: apache, mobile, cordova

After reading the docs, it seems that phonegap/cordova is like a local web server that serves html, js and css to the mobile native browser.

Can phonegap/cordova serve files not only in local ? i want to know if it is possible to make them LAN servers for example, without installing apache on the mobile device??

Thanks.

UPDATE:
I feel i need to describe my probleme.
I need to create a mobile app, that allows mobile devices connected on the same wifi network (without internet) communicate with each others. If this is possible only with phonegap it would be great.

Comment: Cordova/PhoneGap is not a local web server. Cordova creates a simple native application with the main view as a webview. A webview is a simple web browser window capable of doing most tasks that any other browser window can do.

Answer (score 1):

Cordova uses the WebView component to display your content. It's more or less  equivalent to opening html files directly in your desktop browser by going to file > open.

If you want some content on a lan, just link to it in the html that is rolled into the Cordova app as you would load any content in html from an external source.

Comment: Yeah but to share information on LAN I need a server :(

Comment: Well, then that's a web-related question having nothing to do with Cordova. Yes, you'll need a server to host any resources that aren't natively on the phone itself (packaged within the cordova app).